# Facebook Messenger mobile App not displaying images served from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am sending structured messages via the Messenger Mobile App (tested on Android, likely the same issue exists on iOS) and images that are loaded from AWS S3 are not displayed in the app!

However, images are loaded properly on Facebook Messenger Desktop version & and in the Chat window in Facebook. The problem only exists on the mobile app.

As suggested here [How to send an image hosted on Amazon S3 through the Facebook Messenger Send API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411551/how-to-send-an-image-hosted-on-amazon-s3-through-the-facebook-messenger-send-api) I have set my content type on AWS S3 to "image/jpeg".

As suggested here [Messenger not displaying images in Generic template in mobile App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639954/messenger-not-displaying-images-in-generic-template-in-mobile-app) I have named my S3 bucket without dots. Image names i am trying to load have no whitespaces. The image path I am trying to load looks like this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/imagestorage/7892160241445363image1.jpg

I have whitelisted aws s3 domain.

Comment: Can you provide the actual link to an image that isn't working?

Comment: Hey, I managed to prevent this bug. Here's how: I previously tested it on a Facebook app that was not published and it didnt work. Afterwards I moved it to a published app and everything worked out fine as planned. It's super weird, sometimes I don't understand Facebook but right now it seems to work fine on the published app! I do not care about the unpublished app, but would be great if Facebook would fix that bug one day!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I've a slightly different problem...no image shown even if from Amazon itself (https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/...).

Comment: as I said, for me the problem only existed on the unpublished app. Once I used a published facebook app it not longer occurred.